# best way to ignore particular exit code in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Givent the following example

```bash
timeout my_cmd
# if the command is failed due to timeout, aka exit code is 124,
# then the script should contiune to run other commands,
# otherwise it should stop.
# And what if there is more exit code to ignore?
other_cmds
```

I think I may check `$?` to control the running flow, but I want to know if there is any established method for this pattern in Linux.

Comment: After `timeout my_cmd` add `ecode="$?"; if [ "$ecode" -ne 124 ]; then printf "exit code '%s' - exiting.\n" "$ecode"; exit; fi` ??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  That's an option,  thank you. But what if there are more than 1 exit code to be ignored?

Comment: A single task won't output several exit codes - or what are you talking about?

Comment: @tink For example, ignore both 124 and 125, raise error when it is other exit code.

Comment: You get one exit code, if it is `124` continue, if not, exit and show the user what the actual exit code was.

Comment: `case $ecode in 124|125) :;; *) exit "$ecode";; esac`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, after `timeout my_cmd` add:

```bash
timeout my_cmd

ecode="$?"     # save the exit code

# if exit code is not 124, then advise the user and exit
if [ "$ecode" -ne 124 ]; then 
  printf "exit code '%s' - exiting.\n" "$ecode"
  exit "$ecode"
fi

other commands
```

Your script will continue if the exit code is `124`, but exit for all others with the correct exit-code. Let me know if you have questions.

---

With your addition of wanting to check multiple exit codes, then the `case` statement provided by @CharlesDuffy is the best approach. He suggests `case $ecode in 124|125) :;; *) exit "$ecode";; esac` which would fit your needs.  Which in short summary says if `124` or `125` do `:` (a no-op, nothing), for every other exit-code execute the `*` (default) case and `exit`.

For example:

```bash
# if exit code is not 124 or 125, then advise the user and exit
case "$ecode" in
  124|125 ):;;
  * ) 
  printf "exit code '%s' - exiting.\n" "$ecode"
  exit "$ecode";;
esac
```

You can also use an `if` with older syntax and negate the combined check to accomplish the same thing, e.g. you can write the `if` statement as:

```bash
# if exit code is not 124 or 125, then advise the user and exit
if ! [ "$ecode" -eq 124 -o "$ecode" -eq 125 ]; then 
  printf "exit code '%s' - exiting.\n" "$ecode"
  exit "$ecode"
fi
```

It will then perform as you desire, but note the combination of tests with `-o` or `-a` is an older approach and not favored compared to the `||` or `&&` syntax -- but does provide a solution here.